# jQuery UI - detecting if a draggable is over another draggable that has been dropped

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I want to be able to drag a draggable into a droppable. Then, when I drag in another draggable prevent the user from dropping it on the previously dropped draggable, but still drop it on the droppable. That is such a ridiculous sentence I've added an image and a jsfiddle of what I've tried so far here: http://jsfiddle.net/u4pAf/3/

Below is the code on jsfiddle. Just a demo to try and get something working. I though the best approach to detecting if a draggable is over a dropped draggable is to make the draggables droppables too, and set the accept parameter to false, so it accepts nothing.

css:

```
*{ margin:0 }

.draggable-elem { background:red }
.drag1 {width: 100px; height: 40px;}
.drag2 {width: 150px; height: 80px;    margin-top:10px;}

.boundary_active{
    outline: solid 12px darkviolet;
}
.boundary{
    background:cyan; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="boundary">  
    <p>droppable</p>
</div>

<div class="draggable-elem drag1">1</div>
<div class="draggable-elem drag2">2</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery('.boundary').droppable({     
    over : function( event, ui ) { 
        jQuery(ui.helper).css('background', 'blue').text('OVER DROPPABLE'); 
    },
    out : function( event, ui ) { 
        jQuery(ui.helper).css('background', 'red').text('OUTSIDE DROPPABLE'); 
    },
    drop : function(ev, ui) { 
        clone = jQuery(clone.helper).clone(false);
        jQuery('.boundary').append(clone);
    },
    accept : '.draggable-elem',
    activeClass : 'boundary_active',
    tolerance : 'fit'
});

jQuery('.draggable-elem').droppable({
    over : function( event, ui ) { 
        jQuery(ui.helper).css('background', 'yellow').text('OVER DRAGGABLE'); 
    },
    accept : false,
    tolerance : 'fit',
    activeClass : 'boundary_active',
    revert : 'invalid'
});


jQuery( '.draggable-elem' ).draggable({
    helper : 'clone',
});
```